# Search for row/column in csv not working (python)

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
import time, collections, sys, openpyxl, xlrd

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime

## Read the CSV file ##
scanReport = open('scan_report2.csv', 'r')
scanReader = csv.reader(scanReport)

desired_row = "Severity"
## search row's in csv - print out list ##
with open('csvtest.csv', 'w', newline='') as testfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
    print("Checking for Severity Level's...")
    for row in scanReader:
        if desired_row == scanReader:
            print(row)
        else:
            print('Does not match')
```

"severity" is text in my csv file - i can open it fine, however it's not searching and printing the column i want

Comment: I suggest that Pandas will be a better tool for you.  It is very easy to work it out in Pandas.

Comment: By the way, if you do not open a file using 'with open', you need to close it after reading the lines.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You compare the string `desired_row` with the reader object, and expect them to possibly be equal? They will never be, they're not even the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You compare the string `desired_row` with the reader object, so they'll never compare equal. Each row returned from `csvReader` is a list of cell values, so try something like this:

```
for row in scanReader:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.strip() == "Severity":
            print(row)
```

This will match cells that contain just the text `Severity`.

Comment: that will print the row, sorry if i wasn't clear enough, i want it to print everything in the "severity" column, i have a bunch of stuff in the severity column such as number 1-5 that i want to store the value of into an array

Comment: Then edit your question and **explain what you are trying to do** instead of posting code that has no relation to your goals. I think I probably understand, but I'm not going to guess twice.

Comment: And while you're at it, figure out if you want a row or a column and name your variables accordingly.